# TypeError: variable is undefined - Google charts

Tags: arrays, ajax, charts, typeerror, google-visualization

```
I'm getting TypeError: dataArray is undefined:


for (var i=0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
```

Here is my code:

```
 var dataArray = sinAjax(0) ;
            var gdata = new google.visualization.DataTable( );
            //add column labels
            gdata.addColumn ('number', 'x');
            gdata.addColumn ('number', 'sinx');
            //add rows
            for (var i=0; i < dataArray.length; i++) 
            {
                delete dataArray[i].location;
                delete dataArray[i].outcome_status;
                var row = [];        
                for (var item in dataArray[i]) 
                {
                  row.push(dataArray[i][item]);
                }        
                gdata.addRow(row);
             }
```

the function sinAjax(0) returns an array of arrays which I wan to use as google chart points. I have to add columns seperately as they are not in the array.

Edit:

I've now discovered that dataArray is of type undefined. I have tried converting it to an array using:

```
dataArray = $.makeArray(sinAjax(0)) ;
```

However, that just converts it into a javascript object.

How do I convert it to type array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually with my function `sinAjax(0)`, it is an ajax call and I was using a `return` within the success function when I needed it a level higher.

old code:

```
    function sinAjax(xVal)
    {   
        var vArrTestY;

        $.ajax ( {
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                global: false,
                url: "PHP/calcsin.php",
                data:  { x : xVal } ,
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) 
                {
                    console.log("Response");
                    console.log(response );         
                    vArrTestY = JSON.parse(response);   
                    return vArrTestY;
                }
              }  ) ;            

    }
```

new code:

```
function fSinAjax(xVal)
{   
    var vArrTestY;

    $.ajax ( {
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            global: false,
            url: "PHP/calcsin.php",
            data:  { x : xVal } ,
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) 
            {
                console.log("Response");
                console.log(response );         
                vArrTestY = JSON.parse(response);               
            }
          }  ) ;            
    return vArrTestY;
}
```

Comment: Synchronous calls are a bad idea.